# Inkscape: how to apply filter to a sphere, not the square

Tags: inkscape, filter

I would like to apply a filter just to the sphere (see picture), however when I click the filter, it seems to apply to the square surrounding the circle as well. I have no idea why. Is there a way to apply the filter just to the sphere? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: To be honest with you, I wouldn't create this using filters. It can easily be made with filled shapes, gradients, and blurred objects. The quality will be much better if you do it that way. [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/NWbEdYa)

Comment: Just, mask it...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this filter casts shadow. You can do following:

1. Try different filter
2. Try manually remove shadow in Filters -> Filter editor.
3. In Filters -> Filter editor, find filter parameters, and change size of filter (make it bigger). So filter bounds will not cut shadow